# How to make padding of container tap-able?

Tags: flutter

I want to be able to click the padding around the GestureDetector widget and trigger onTap method of it. I dont want to change the size of the Icon itself. Here is the code so far.

```
class InfoButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double padding;
  static const double defaultPadding = 5;

  const InfoButton({Key key, @required this.text, this.padding = defaultPadding}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.info_outline,
          color: Colors.blue,
          size: 20,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          print('clicked');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to I achieve this in flutter?

Comment: Just set the container as child of Gesture Detector. But there are better ways of creating buttons with Icons, like: **RawMaterialButton** or **IconButton**

Comment: I was actually going to use IconButton but it sets default of 48 pixels all around the icon in order to comply with the material design guideline. But I needed custom padding size.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just include `Container` as the child of `GestureDetector` instead of the `Icon` and set `behavior` property of `GestureDetector` to `HitTestBehavior.opaque` like this

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return GestureDetector(
             behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                  onTap: () {
                    print('clicked');
                  },
              child : Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 20,
                  )
                ),
              );
            }
```

Comment: I actually needed to set behaviour field of GestureDetector to HitTestBehavior.opaque in your code for it to work as intended

Comment: Please change your code so that I can accept it as correct answer

Comment: Isn't it working without the `behaviour` property as well?

Comment: No unfortunately

Comment: I just checked and it is working for me, you shouldn't need `behaviour` for this. You also said earlier that it worked, What happened then?

Comment: I was using behavior property with my former code. But it was not working. When I applied your suggestions I forgot to omit behavior property. That is why I said it worked. My mistake really. I tried multiple times without behavior, but cant trigger onTap when I click on paddings.

Comment: I have added `behaviour` but I am pretty sure it should work without that, I have tested it.

Comment: Yes I have tested it in real environment.

Comment: I have no idea what would be the reason for situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191871/discussion-between-keerti-purswani-and-lisiram).

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer, sometimes you're unable to use the `GestureDetector` (and don't have access to its `behavior` prop), but you also need the `Container`'s paddings to be clickable. For example, inside a `DragStartListener`.

In this case, *the Container can be given a non-transparent color in order for the hits to be detected*. Example:

```dart
ReorderableDragStartListener(
  index: index,
  child: Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 50,
    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0001), // <-- non-transparent color
    child: Icon(
      Icons.drag_indicator,
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline,
    ),
  ),
);
```

With this little "hack" the wrapping container detects the hits not only on the `Icon` inside the `Container`, but on the `Container` itself.